# Vue 2.0 Share live data component to another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, containers, vuejs2

> **Edit :** i started to use VUEX to store all my data there.

---

I have a container with some components, every component have data, i got every component data on my container data, but isn't "live", here's the code example

> Container "father.vue"

```
import JobDetails from 'components/searchPosition/jobDetails.vue'
export default {
  components: { JobDetails },
  data () {
    return {
      attributes: {
        jobTitle: JobDetails.data().jobTitle,
        ... more data ...
      }
    }
```

> Component "son.vue"

```
export default {
  components: { },
  data () {
    return {
      jobTitle: 'Test',
      ..more data..
    }
  }
```

so in my template im printing jobTitle only to check if im doing good, but not!

```
<pre>
  {{ attributes.jobTitle }} < this value it's an input, if i change the value (typing) wont change on my container data
</pre>
```

there's a way to get "live" data from another component?

Comment: All of what you need is covered here. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components

Answer (score 1):

You're actually "hurting" the principle of the **Single source of truth** which is also covered in the link provided by Bert Evans in the comments.

You can ofcourse have "live" data and updates between components, but not like this.

Usually you would define the data on your parent element and propagate it down to your children. On changes within the child you will need to tell the paren to update itself. Don't update props directly! Here a small example.

**Parent**

```
...
data: function() {
   return { text: '' }
},

methods: {
   updateText: function(sText) {
      this.text = sText;
   }
}
...
```

**Child**

```
...
data: function() { return { tmp: '' } },
props: ['text'],
created: function() {
  this.tmp = this.text;
},
methods: {
  emitChange: function() {
    this.$emit('update', this.tmp);
  }
}
...
```

**Template for child**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input @input="emitChange" v-model="tmp" />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Template of parent**

```
<template>
   <div>
      <child :text="text" @update="updateText" />
   </div>
</template>
```

Explained in short:

- parent is the element holding the actual text for all components
- child components have an internal tmp that is initially set to text
- changes on this tmp value will be used to update the initial text of parent
- changes are emited and the parent is listening to these emits

Problems with current example

- the shown example has no actual connection between tmp and text within your child. Changes from other child components would be overwritten - so don't use this exact code if you don't want this behaviour. However, hopefully the general concept is now clearer.

Comment: This is a good answer, i tried and works, but i decide to dont do it on this way because your advice "hurting" the principle of the Single source of truth.